# spark dataframe - dynamic substring based on numbers in strings

Tags: arrays, regex, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Convert the given spark dataframe (Spark version 2.0, scala 2.11),

```
A   B
a   2*Z12*CA9*ThisnThat10*51827630323*fa2
b   1*C7*Friends5*names1*O2
c   4*19456*helpme6*please
d   2*M13*fin2*na2*325*123456*fancy2
```

to the following format (in scala or pyspark ).

```
A   B
a   Z1*CA*ThisnThat*5182763032*fa2
b   C*Friends*names*O
c   1945*helpme*please
d   M1*fin*na*32*12345*fancy2
```

Logic used - in each row, use the first numeric value to substring the next value.  Use the remaining numeric part to extract the next value and so on....

e.g. for the first string

```
(2*Z12*CA9*ThisnThat10*51827630323*fa2) - 
* Use the first 2 to break 'Z12' into 'Z1' (two characters) with 2 remaining.  
* Use this 2 to break 'CA9' into 'CA' (two characters) with 9 remaining.  
* Use this 9 to break 'ThisnThat10' into 'ThisnThat' (9 characters) and 10.  
* Use the 10 to break '51827630323' into '5182763032' (10 characters) and 3.  
* Use the 3 to break 'fa2' into 'fa2' (3 characters).
```

I can split string and create wide dataframe with dynamic number of columns - but I cannot figure out an UDF for shortening strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have following `dataframe` (data taken from question)

```
+---+-------------------------------------+
|A  |B                                    |
+---+-------------------------------------+
|a  |2*Z12*CA9*ThisnThat10*51827630323*fa2|
|b  |1*C7*Friends5*names1*O2              |
|c  |4*19456*helpme6*please               |
|d  |2*M13*fin2*na2*325*123456*fancy2     |
+---+-------------------------------------+
```

Then you *need a recursive function inside udf function* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def shorteningUdf = udf((actualStr: String) => {
  val arrayStr = actualStr.split("\\*")
  val nextSubStrIndex = arrayStr.head.toInt
  val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[String]
  def recursiveFund(arrayStr2: List[String], index: Int, resultStrBuff: ListBuffer[String]): ListBuffer[String] = arrayStr2 match{
    case head :: Nil => resultStrBuff += head.splitAt(index)._1
    case head :: tail => {
      val splitStr = head.splitAt(index)
      recursiveFund(tail, splitStr._2.toInt, resultStrBuff += splitStr._1)
    }
    case _ => resultStrBuff
  }
  recursiveFund(arrayStr.tail.toList, nextSubStrIndex, listBuffer).mkString("*")
})
```

so when you call the `udf` function

```
df.withColumn("B", shorteningUdf(col("B"))).show(false)
```

You will get your desired output

```
+---+------------------------------+
|A  |B                             |
+---+------------------------------+
|a  |Z1*CA*ThisnThat*5182763032*fa2|
|b  |C*Friends*names*O             |
|c  |1945*helpme*please            |
|d  |M1*fin*na*32*12345*fancy2     |
+---+------------------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can create a UDF to process column `B` as below.  `Try` is used for validating integer conversion, and `foldLeft` is used to traverse the split substrings to carry out the required processing logic.

Note that a `tuple` of (String, Integer) is used as the accumulator for `foldLeft` to iteratively transform the string as well as to carry over the calculated length value (`n`).

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a", "2*Z12*CA9*ThisnThat10*51827630323*fa2"),
  ("b", "1*C7*Friends5*names1*O2"),
  ("c", "4*19456*helpme6*please"),
  ("d", "2*M13*fin2*na2*325*123456*fancy2")
).toDF("A", "B")

def processString = udf( (s: String) => {
  import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

  val arr = s.split("\\*")
  val firstN = Try(arr.head.toInt) match {
    case Success(i) => i
    case Failure(_) => 0
  }

  arr.tail.foldLeft( ("", firstN) ){ (acc, x) =>
    val n = Try( x.drop(acc._2).toInt ) match {
      case Success(i) => i
      case Failure(_) => 0
    }
    ( acc._1 + "*" + x.take(acc._2), n )
  }._1.tail
} )

df.select($"A", processString($"B").as("B")).
  show(false)
// +---+------------------------------+
// |A  |B                             |
// +---+------------------------------+
// |a  |Z1*CA*ThisnThat*5182763032*fa2|
// |b  |C*Friends*names*O             |
// |c  |1945*helpme*please            |
// |d  |M1*fin*na*32*12345*fancy2     |
// +---+------------------------------+
```